# Show account information in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to find some way to retrieve information from the control panel in a google apps script gadget in a Google site once a user logs in to his Google account.

I found one way to [run the script as the user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#permissions) and used the function [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser%28%29) and deploy it in the apps script gadget.

Did not work and an error appeared "the script worked perfectly but did not return anything."

Any solutions for this problem? Or did I miss some other good way to show the information needed?

Comment: Can you post some code. Looking at the question, it appears that you have a doGet() but did not return an UiApp from the doGet.

Comment: `function doGet(e) {

var value = logActiveUserEmail();
  return value;
}

 function logActiveUserEmail() {
   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   Logger.log(email);
 }
`
There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are not returning an UiApp object. See [Ui Service documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp) for information on how to display an UI. At a very basic level you can use the following code

```
function doGet(e) 
{
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
 var value = logActiveUserEmail();
 app.add(app.createLabel('Your email address is ' + value));

 // Return the UI App
 return app; 
} 

function logActiveUserEmail() 
{
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 Logger.log(email); 
 return email;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I lack too much sorry I am new to this, Thanks for the info about the UIApp and thanks for your help =)